# Tag merge: steam-cloud to steam

Tags: discussion, tag-merging

We have [steam-cloud](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam-cloud) which is clearly about the cloud service that is part of Steam, although I feel that this isn't required. A lot of games utilise this feature in one way or another and each question always features the [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) tag so how do you feel about merging them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is possible for someone to be an expert on the steam cloud service (since it is a concrete service) without wanting to wade through problems with steam games (since that is often how the tag is used).